# Length of an HTMLCollection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to gather all the "li" in my document by doing this:

```
var first = document.getElementById("scroll-container").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Now I need to know how many are them so I tried those calls:

```
console.log(first.length);
```

and

```
console.log(document.getElementById("scroll-container").getElementsByTagName("li").length);
```

But none of them worked, they just show a 0 even though in the console when I check what's inside "first" there appears to be a "length" field. Can someone help me to access it?

**EDIT**

The solutions you propose are not working, maybe it's because the "li" sections aren't static. Inside the "div" "scroll-container" I create a "li" for each field in a .json file I read, like this:

```
$.getJSON( "list.json", function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(i, field){
  $.each(field, function(key, value){
    $("#scroll-container").append("<li id='scroll_part1'><p class='row'>"+value.nom+"</p></li>");
  });
 });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're using with?

Comment: If you want all the li elements in your document, what if you try document.getElementsByTagName('li').length?  Also, you can try document.querySelectorAll('li').length for the non-nodelist version.  The length property should work if the items are found.

Comment: Also, if you can provide a fiddle or link to your code, we can probably be of more help.

Answer (score 2):

You've tagged this question with jQuery, so here's a simple jQuery solution:

```
var first = $('#scroll-container li').first();
```

Or to get the number of `li` within the element:

```
var liCount = $('#scroll-container li').length;
```

Comment: That didn't work, maybe it's because the "li" aren't static. I create a "li" for each field of a .json file. I edited the post to add this info.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect an error in your markup. Given the HTML:

```
<ul id="scroll-container">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

and javascript:

```
var listItems = document.getElementById("scroll-container").getElementsByTagName("li");

console.log(listItems.length)
```

It performs as expected and returns `2`

Comment: That didn't work, maybe it's because the "li" aren't static. I create a "li" for each field of a .json file. I edited the post to add this info.

Comment: Well that would explain things... you need to have this function execute in the callback after you get/parse your JSON.

Comment: Post your code for how you're getting the JSON and parsing them into <li>s